# How to iterate over all but the last index of an AbstractArray

Tags: iteration, julia

In Julia, the recommended way to iterate over all indices of an `AbstractArray` is to use `eachindex`, e.g.,

```
for i in eachindex(a)
    do_something(a[i], i)
end
```

In contrast to `1:length(a)`, `eachindex(a)` supports arrays with unconventional indexing, i.e., indices not starting at `1`. Additionally, it is more efficient for arrays with slow linear indexing.

If I want to skip the first index I can use `Iterators.drop(eachindex(a), 1)` (is there a better way?) but how do I skip the last one in a generic way?

Comment: `length` is defined for `AbstractArray` so you could for example use `take(eachindex(a), length(a)-1)`.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Unfortunately not, if I understand this correctly: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/devdocs/offset-arrays.html#Arrays-with-custom-indices-1.

Comment: `eachindex` should return something that supports `length` in practice, even for unconventionally indexed arrays.

Comment: Not `length` surely, but rather `endof` is to be used here.

Comment: No, `length` is correct, as we are taking a fixed number of elements from the iterator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "front" iterator is relatively simple and generally useful. **Edit**: it's also totally overkill to define it in full generality just for this case.  It's much easier and simpler to rely on Base's builtins with a definition like:

```
front(itr, n=1) = Iterators.take(itr, length(itr)-n)
```

This will work for all iterators with `length` defined — which will include everything that `eachindex` will return.

---

Alternatively, you can define a specialized iterator from first principles that doesn't depend upon `length` being defined. I'm not aware of such a structure in any existing packages. Using Julia 0.6, an implementation could look like:

```
struct Front{T}
    itr::T
end
# Basic iterator definition
function Base.start(f::Front)
    s = start(f.itr)
    done(f.itr, s) && throw(ArgumentError("cannot take the front of an empty iterator"))
    return next(f.itr, s)
end
function Base.next(f::Front, state)
    val, s = state
    return val, next(f.itr, s)
end
Base.done(f::Front, state) = done(f.itr, state[2])

# Inherit traits as appropriate
Base.iteratorsize(::Type{Front{T}}) where {T} = _dropshape(Base.iteratorsize(T))
_dropshape(x) = x
_dropshape(::Base.HasShape) = Base.HasLength()
Base.iteratoreltype(::Type{Front{T}}) where {T} = Base.iteratoreltype(T)
Base.length(f::Front) = length(f.itr) - 1
Base.eltype(f::Front{T}) where {T} = eltype(T)
```

Now:

```
julia> collect(Front(eachindex(rand(5))))
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4

julia> collect(Front(eachindex(sprand(3, 2, .2))))
5-element Array{CartesianIndex{2},1}:
 CartesianIndex{2}((1, 1))
 CartesianIndex{2}((2, 1))
 CartesianIndex{2}((3, 1))
 CartesianIndex{2}((1, 2))
 CartesianIndex{2}((2, 2))
```

Comment: What's the performance overhead of this? I imagine it would be faster to optimize `front(itr)` in the case that `iteratorsize(itr) == HasLength()` or `iteratorsize(itr) == HasShape()` by `take(itr, length(itr)-1)`.

Comment: I imagine it's _exactly_ the same as the `take` iterator.  Might need to sprinkle in an `@inline` or two, but there should be no overhead.

Comment: `Take` is consistently a little faster for me, but both are way slower than `view` in the case that the iterator is an array. I wonder why `take` is not specialized to call view in those cases; it should support a superset of the functionality that the `Take` iterator supports.

Comment: It looks like `next` just needs to be `@inline`'ed (and `done` for `Take`).  Then they both rival `view`.

Comment: Nevertheless, it would still make sense for `take(OneTo(n), m)` to return `OneTo(min(n, m))`, and a similar method for `UnitRange`. This would eliminate overhead in two of the most common `eachindex` cases. I may come up with a PR later.

Comment: Great solution! For `a=rand(100,100,100)` and julia 0.5, `front(itr, n=1) = take(itr, length(itr)-n)`, `Front` with inlined `next`, and naive iteration with `1:length(a)-1` all need 2.3ms on my PC. On Julia 0.6, the letter two are equally faster with 0.8ms but the first takes `7.7ms`. If I didn't do anything stupid, the full `Front` iterator is the way to go. Of course, specialization of `take` on `OneTo` removes the overhead in this case, too.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to define @MattB.'s `Front` is

```
front(itr,n=1) = (first(x) for x in Iterators.partition(itr,n+1,1))
```

This also gives:

```
julia> front(eachindex([1,2,3,4,5]))|>collect
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

and as a bonus:

```
julia> front(eachindex([1,2,3,4,5]),2)|>collect
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
```

the corresponding iterator to `drop(eachindex([1,2,3,4,5]),2)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach is significantly slower than Matt B.'s solution in my tests.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the following:

`for I in CartesianRange(Base.front(indices(A)))
    @show I A[I, :]
end`

On `A = reshape(1:27, 3, 3, 3)` this yields

`I = CartesianIndex{2}((1,1))
A[I,:] = [1,10,19]
I = CartesianIndex{2}((2,1))
A[I,:] = [2,11,20]
I = CartesianIndex{2}((3,1))
A[I,:] = [3,12,21]
I = CartesianIndex{2}((1,2))
A[I,:] = [4,13,22]
I = CartesianIndex{2}((2,2))
A[I,:] = [5,14,23]
I = CartesianIndex{2}((3,2))
A[I,:] = [6,15,24]
I = CartesianIndex{2}((1,3))
A[I,:] = [7,16,25]
I = CartesianIndex{2}((2,3))
A[I,:] = [8,17,26]
I = CartesianIndex{2}((3,3))
A[I,:] = [9,18,27]`

Comment: I think the question asker intended "last index" to mean something different than this answer does.

Comment: Correct, I want to skip the last index in the linear index of `A`, i.e., loop over 26 indices in this example. How to skip the complete last dimension is still good to know.